# 1999 Ford Interceptor 4.6 L not starting

Tags: ford, starting

After replacing the intake the car will not start. The lights on the dash come on, the fuel pump pumps, the fuel rail has been bled. And yet when I turn the key, no click just some relay clicks after a second or two. Starter does not click or appear to work at all. It appears everything is reconnected. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to garner a guess on the information you've provided, it seems the solenoid on the starter is not getting energized. This could be caused from one of several different things.

First, is the energizer wire connected to the starter solenoid? This should be the smaller wire going to the solenoid, not the large one coming from the battery.

Second, check the relay which energizes the starter solenoid. This should be in the fuse box under the hood. When you find it, you can check it by changing it out with another relay.

Third, are you sure the starter/solenoid is good? Is there any way it could have gone bad while sitting? Stranger things have happened. If you were careful, you could apply power directly to the main power lead coming OUT of the solenoid going into the starter. The idea here is to just hit it with power to ensure the starter is working correctly. To do this, you'd have to connect a large gauge cable (probably a jumper cable) to the power lead, then briefly connecting the other end to the positive post on the battery. You could also try to energize the solenoid directly to see if it is working. If you are not comfortable doing this on the car, take the starter off first and bench test it (by far the safest option).